# Small exercise about regularity of the Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, compactness

I have problems with this exercise.

Let $K ⊆ \mathbb{R}$ be compact with $λ(K) > 0$. I have to show that there is an open set $U$, so
that $K ⊆ U ⊆ \mathbb{R}$ with $λ(U) < 2λ(K)$.

I wanted to use the regularity of the Lebesgue measure but I really don´t know how to do it.

Comment: Begin with writing down (in your post) what (outer) "regularity of the Lebesgue measure" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lambda (K)=\inf \{\lambda (U): U \text {open}, K \subseteq U\}$. So $\lambda (K)+\epsilon >\lambda (U)$ with $U$ open, $ K \subseteq U$. This gives  $\lambda (K)+\epsilon > \frac 1 2\lambda (U)+\epsilon$ provided $0<\epsilon < \frac 1 2 \lambda (K)$ (because $\lambda (K)  \leq \lambda (U)$).